# ClassNotFoundException when trying to bulk load into titan using a Java MapReduce job

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, titan, tinkerpop

We're currently trying to bulk load some files from HDFS into titan using a map reduce job and the titan dependencies. However, we're running into an issue once the map jobs start where it can't find a tinkerpop class. This is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex
```

I read somewhere that Titan 1.0.0 is only compatible with Tinkerpop 3.0.1-incubating, so that's what our versions are for dependencies.
It might help to see our pom.xml and code

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>replacementID</groupId>
  <artifactId>replacementID</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
        <artifactId>titan-hbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-gremlin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Mapper:

```
package edu.rosehulman.brubakbd;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraph;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanVertex;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;

public class TitanMRMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{


    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] vals = line.split("\t");

        BaseConfiguration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
                conf.setProperty("gremlin.graph", "com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory");
                conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "hbase");
                conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", "hadoop-16.csse.rose-hulman.edu");
                conf.setProperty("storage.batch-loading", true);
                conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure");
                conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.ext.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", 2181);
                conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache",true);
                conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-clean-wait", 20);
                conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-time", 180000);
                conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-size", 0.5);


        TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
        TitanVertex v1 = graph.addVertex();
        v1.property("pageID", vals[0]);
        TitanVertex v2 = graph.addVertex();
        v2.property("pageID", vals[1]);

        v1.addEdge("links_To", v2);

        graph.tx().commit();
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat;

public class TitanMR {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if (args.length != 1){
            System.err.println("Usage: TitanMR <input path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(TitanMR.class);
        job.setJobName("TitanMR");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        job.setOutputFormatClass(NullOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(TitanMRMapper.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        System.out.println("about to submit job");
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the `gremlin-core.jar` and the other dependencies are on the `CLASSPATH`. How are you running your job? Via Maven? Via Gremlin Console?

Comment: We're building a jar through maven, then trying to run the MR job on a hadoop cluster using the command 'yarn jar TitanMR.jar /pathToData'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you look into creating an uber-jar that contains all of your project dependencies. Since you're using Apache Maven for your build, you use the [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or the [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Comment: I'll try those. I attempted to put the gremlin-core-3.0.1-incubating.jar in the classpath of hadoop, but it still can't find the class.

Comment: For the most part doing an uber-jar has worked. However, we're now running into a new error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager

Its root cause is still a class not found:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseCompat1_00

Comment: Try adding this to your Titan base configuration `conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.compat-class", "com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseCompat1_0");` https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-hbase-parent/titan-hbase-10/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/diskstorage/hbase/HBaseCompat1_0.java#L14

Comment: Well, it fixed part of the error. We're now getting a different roots for the error, but I'm not sure it's going to work. My team is just planning on giving up on distributed bulk loading and resorting to bulk loading from local data of a single node. Thanks for your help! I'm going to mark this as the solution as it did fix our classNotFound exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your gremlin jars in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-gremlin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
    <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
    <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The TinkerPop 3.2.3 jars are not compatible with Titan 1.0.0. The original post is correct that [TinkerPop 3.0.1](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L62) should be used.